# Booting up Vagrant from Jenkins throws Permission Denied

Tags: jenkins, vagrant, jenkins-plugins, vagrant-plugin

I am trying to Boot up Vagrant VM from Jenkins. I gave Vagrantfile path in 'Boot up Vagrant VM'.
When the job runs, I get the following error:

```
Failed to iterate on remote directory vagrant_projs
[ vagrant ]: Executing command :[vagrant, up] in folder /Users/abc/Desktop/vagrant_projs
[vagrant_projs] $ vagrant up
[ vagrant ]: Error starting up vagrant, caught IOException, message: Cannot run program "vagrant" (in directory "/Users/abc/Desktop/vagrant_projs"): error=13, Permission denied
[ vagrant ]: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@5e144dc9
Build step 'Boot up Vagrant VM' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I thought it might be because of permissions of Vagrantfile and thus I have chmod 777 to it manually. Even after that it gives me the same error.

**UPDATE:**
I moved the folder in which *Vagrantfile* resided from Desktop to user folder and I got different stacktrace.

```
[workspace] $ vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.7.2
[ vagrant ]: Executing command :[vagrant, up] in folder /Users/abalan15/vagrant_projs
[vagrant_projs] $ vagrant up
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:313:in `unlink': Permission denied - /Users/abalan15/vagrant_projs/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id (Errno::EACCES)
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:313:in `delete'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:313:in `id='
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:142:in `initialize'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:75:in `new'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:75:in `machine'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:614:in `machine'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:168:in `block in with_target_vms'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:192:in `call'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:192:in `block in with_target_vms'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:174:in `each'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:174:in `with_target_vms'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/commands/up/command.rb:74:in `block in execute'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:277:in `block (2 levels) in batch'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:275:in `tap'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:275:in `block in batch'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:274:in `synchronize'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:274:in `batch'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/commands/up/command.rb:58:in `execute'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:301:in `cli'
from /opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/bin/vagrant:174:in `<main>'
Build step 'Boot up Vagrant VM' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Has it ever worked or did it fail from the start? It still looks like a permission failure, but on your `/Users/abalan15` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last!
When we try to invoke/boot Vagrant VM from Jenkins(with vagrant plugin), *.vagrant.d* & *folder with vagrantfile* will be invoked. Permission for the jenkins user should be given to these folders.

In mac, right click on these folders, get info, on the bottom(permissions), click the + symbol and add jenkins to the *'Users & Groups'*

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check when dealing with permission problems in Jenkins:

- What user name is running the container (Tomcat) or the Jenkins native binary?
- What user name is the jenkins process / jnlp / slave using (if this isn't on the master Jenkins node)